# Evitar um plano Cartesiano em um join com 2 tabelas com duplicidades

Tags: join

[image: TABLEA E TABLEB]

De acordo com a imagem acima:

O campo `A1` da `TableA` possui dois valores duplicados que é a chave 3 e a `TableB` com o campo `B1` possui os mesmos valores duplicados.

Eu queria fazer um `inner join` entre as duas tabelas usando os campos `A1` da `TableA` e `B1` da `TableB` como chaves e trazer como resultados os
valores dos campos `A2` e `B2` sem gerar um cartesiano.

Resultado pretendido:

```
A2 B2 
a   a
b   a    
c   c 
d   f
```

Tentei fazer:

```
Select  A2, b.B2 
    from Table_A as a 
    inner join Table_B  as b
    on a.a1 = b.b1
```

Resultado adquirido com a *query* acima:

```
A2, B2
a   a
b   a
c   c
d   c
c   f
d   f
```

Comment: Deco, vi que ainda não fez o [tour] pelo site, então convido-te a fazê-lo. Será importante para você aprender o básico de como o site funciona.

Comment: Tem como você detalhar melhor que tipo de relacionamento é esse? E informe-nos qual é o banco de dados que está utilizando. Você pode adicionar um [link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eXwWu6ybF5sxG7hGqSX5K5/0) assim para exemplificar o que está tentando fazer.

Comment: Essas informações representam algo real? Pois parece que você implementou uma relação muitos para muitos, mas não quer isso. Qual a relação entre `c` e `d` em `TableA` para possuir o mesmo valor de `A1`? E por quê esse valor variou para `d`? O mesmo para a tabela `Table2`. A estrutura do banco está bem confusa e parece não ser a ideal para representar a relação entre os registros.

Comment: Isso é apenas o resultado pretendido, não a descrição da relação entre as tabelas. Você tem conhecimento sobre banco de dados relacional? O que são esses registros? Por quê esses valores se repetem? Por quê não quer o produto entre as tabelas? Não faz sentido `c` e `f` possuírem o mesmo valor é não estarem relacionados. O mesmo com `d` e `c`, por isso eu digo que parece que a estrutura das tabelas não condiz com a relação desejada. Por favor, explique, não apenas com o resultado esperado.

Comment: Isto não é algo real é apenas um teste que recebi. E gostaria de saber se dentro deste cenário caótico usando um inner join seria possivel não obter um cartesiano, ou seja no campo: A1 o primeiro valor 3 se corresponda com o primeiro valor 3 do campo:B1 ,e que o segundo valor 3 do campo: A1 se corresponda com o segundo valor 3 do campo:B1. Evitando assim um cartesiano. É claro que as outras chaves se corresponderiam normalmento pois não existem duplicidades nas chaves 1 e 2 de ambas as tabelas. Não sei se consegui me expressar bem. Desde já agradeço. O tour foi feito. Gracias

Comment: Eu sei que usando o Distinct isto não funcionario, pois a linha não está duplicada e sim o campo usado como chave. Se dentro deste cenário não tiver o que fazer além de aceitar o cartesiano td bem. Acredito que isto é uma pegadinha da empresa que aplicou o teste e por isto gostaria de saber se existe outras possibilidades de resolver isto? Talvez criar novos indices para cada tabela?

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela sua ajuda Anderson Carlos Woss, pessoas assim como vc precisamos. Semeando o conhecimento.

Comment: Não sei se isso foi ironia, mas espero que não. Se for, reveja os conceitos da comunidade refazendo o tour. Dado que ninguém respondeu ainda, pode ser impossível fazer da maneira que está. Mas talvez a pergunta só não teve atenção suficiente. Se quiser, pode editá-la brevemente e, assim, ela voltará para a página inicial. Quando tiver reputação, poderá oferecer uma recompensa pela resposta. Boa sorte.